# How to get a Listener in Eclipse FormPage

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am adding 3 pages inside an editor through Eclipse's FormPage. Now on selecting each page I want a listener to get fired. I tried to implement `IPageListener` in each page class, but none of them responded me. How to get the listener while selecting any page in eclipse FormPage?

I have made a FormEditor class,

```
public class SimpleFormEditor extends FormEditor
```

Then I added addPage inside it,

```
addPage(new ApplicationFormPage(this));
```

Now in this ApplicationFormPage, I implemented IPageListener,

```
public class ApplicationFormPage extends FormPage implements IPageListener{
```

Actually my plan is to get the listener as soon as we click on this page tab.

Comment: You added a listener to the FormEditor, right?  Please show us a snippet of code, or even pseudocode.  Or do you mean you put multiple pages within one FormPage instead of the FormEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your form page is instantiated, you need to add it to something in order to get notified of page changes.  In MultiPageEditorPart they use org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.IPageChangedListener.

```
formEditor.addPageChangedListener(page);
```